# Property not readable on a inner class in a TreeModel

Tags: java, mvvm, treeview, zk

Here i have a `ManagePageSource` which provide Model for TreeView using `mvvm` pattern of zk.
`ManagePageSource` has a inner class `Node` to hold treeNode Data.
`Node` has a name property and zk is not able to read it in zul file.

```
public class ManagePageSource implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private TreeModel treeModel = null;

    public TreeModel getTreeModel() {
        TreeNode<Node>[] children = null;
            // create a node
        TreeNode<Node> node = new DefaultTreeNode<Node>(new Node("child"), children);
        // add child node to a node
        node.add(new DefaultTreeNode<Node>(new Node("child2")));
            // create treeModel and set nodes
        treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(node);

        return treeModel;
    }

    // Inner class for holding tree data
    class Node implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String name = null;
        public Node(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

}
```

---

Manage.zul

```
<window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
    viewModel="@id('vm') @init('ManagePageSource')">
    <tree model="@load(vm.treeModel)">
        <treecols>
            <treecol label="Path" />
        </treecols>
        <template name="model">
            <treeitem>
                <treerow>
                    <treecell label="@load(each.data.name)" />
                </treerow>
            </treeitem>
        </template>
    </tree>
</window>
```

error stack

```
>>org.zkoss.zel.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'name' not readable on type ManagePageSource$Node
>>  at org.zkoss.zel.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.read(BeanELResolver.java:409)
>>  at org.zkoss.zel.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.access$000(BeanELResolver.java:320)
```

Why name is not readable here ?

Answer (score 0):

Use modifier `public`  before `Node` class,Because of the Node class method can't access outside.

```
 public class ManagePageSource implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private TreeModel treeModel = null;

    public TreeModel getTreeModel() {
        TreeNode<Node>[] children = null;
            // create a node
        TreeNode<Node> node = new DefaultTreeNode<Node>(new Node("child"), children);
        // add child node to a node
        node.add(new DefaultTreeNode<Node>(new Node("child2")));
            // create treeModel and set nodes
        treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(node);

        return treeModel;
    }

    // Inner class for holding tree data
 public   class Node implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String name = null;
        public Node(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No...changed error...SEVERE: >>org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException: Property 'name' not found on type org.zkoss.zul.DefaultTreeNode at [jndi:/localhost/manage.zul, line:10] >>org.zkoss.zel.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'name' not found on type org.zkoss.zul.DefaultTreeNode >> at org.zkoss.zel.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:304)

Answer (score 0):

`name` was not readable, because the `Node` class wasn't public. Changing that fixed the problem.