# ZK inner class tree property not readable

Tags: java, ajax, properties, tree, zk

I have almost the same problem as this question:
[Property not readable on a inner class in a TreeModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477396/property-not-readable-on-a-inner-class-in-a-treemodel)

But the same solution seems not applicable.

I have a tree, and as I implemented my Entity, and my TreeModel, and they are working just fine, on my .zul file my "data" property isn't found on the treecell.

Here's some of the code:

-The structure implementation, that runs @AfterCompose:

```
 private void montarEstrutura(){

    Unidade ub1 = new Unidade();
    ub1.setParent(null);
    ub1.setNumero("NBase");
    ub1.setDescricao("DBase");

    Unidade ub2 = new Unidade();
    ub2.setParent(ub1);
    ub2.setNumero("N002");
    ub2.setDescricao("D002");

        Unidade ub4 = new Unidade();
        ub4.setParent(ub2);
        ub4.setNumero("N004");
        ub4.setDescricao("D004");

            Unidade ub6 = new Unidade();
            ub6.setParent(ub4);
            ub6.setNumero("N006");
            ub6.setDescricao("D006");

            Unidade ub7 = new Unidade();
            ub7.setParent(ub4);
            ub7.setNumero("N007");
            ub7.setDescricao("D007");

            Unidade ub8 = new Unidade();
            ub8.setParent(ub4);
            ub8.setNumero("N008");
            ub8.setDescricao("D008");

        Unidade ub5 = new Unidade();
        ub5.setParent(ub2);
        ub5.setNumero("N005");
        ub5.setDescricao("D005");

    Unidade ub3 = new Unidade();
    ub3.setParent(ub1);
    ub3.setNumero("N003");
    ub3.setDescricao("D003");


    List<Unidade> lub3 = new ArrayList<Unidade>();
    lub3.add(ub6);
    lub3.add(ub7);
    lub3.add(ub8);

    ub4.setUnidades(lub3);

    List<Unidade> lub2 = new ArrayList<Unidade>();
    lub2.add(ub4);
    lub2.add(ub5);
    ub2.setUnidades(lub2);

    List<Unidade> lub1 = new ArrayList<Unidade>();
    lub1.add(ub2);
    lub1.add(ub3);
    ub1.setUnidades(lub1);

    unidadeTreeModel = new UnidadeTreeModel(ub1);
    tree.setModel(unidadeTreeModel);

}
```

-The entity is pretty long, so I'll cut it:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Unidade extends AbstractSuseTools{

private String numero;
private String descricao;

    @OneToMany
private List<Unidade> unidades = new LinkedList<Unidade>();

    public String getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(String numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}
public List<Unidade> getUnidades() {
    return unidades;
}

public void setUnidades(List<Unidade> unidades) {
    this.unidades = unidades;
}
}
```

And here's the .zul file, that does not reads the property of the entity:

```
<div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
     viewModel="@id('vm') @init('br.com.simplesmenteuse.viewmodel.basico.OrganizacaoViewModel')"    >
   <tree id="tree" model="@load(vm.unidadeTreeModel)" selectedItem="@bind(vm.unidadeSelected)" >
        <treecols>
            <treecol width="100px" label="Editar" />
            <treecol width="100px" label="Excluir" />
            <treecol hflex="4" label="Número" />
            <treecol hflex="1" label="Nome" />
        </treecols>
        <template name="model">
            <treeitem>
                <treerow>
                    <treecell label="Editar"/>
                    <treecell label="Excluir"/>
                    <treecell label="@load(each.numero)"/>
                    <treecell label="@load(each.descricao)"/>
                </treerow>
            </treeitem>
        </template>
    </tree>
```

My TreeModel:

```
    public class UnidadeTreeModel extends AbstractTreeModel<Unidade> {
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3854683349236034878L;

    public UnidadeTreeModel(Unidade unidade){
        super(unidade);
    }

    public boolean isLeaf(Unidade node) {
        return getLevel(node.toString()) >= 4; //at most 4 levels;
    }
    public Unidade getChild(Unidade parent, int index) {
        if(((Unidade)parent).getUnidades() != null && ((Unidade)parent).getUnidades().size() > index)
            return ((Unidade)parent).getUnidades().get(index);
        else
            return null;
    }
    public int getChildCount(Unidade parent) {
        return (((Unidade)parent).getUnidades() != null)?((Unidade)parent).getUnidades().size():0;
    }
    public int getIndexOfChild(Unidade parent, Unidade child) {
        for (int i  = 0; i<parent.getUnidades().size();i++) {
            if (child.equals(parent.getUnidades().get(i))) { return i;}
        }
        return -1; //or throw exception what you want.
    }
    private int getLevel(String data) {
        for (int i = -1, level = 0;; ++level)
            if ((i = data.indexOf('.', i + 1)) < 0)
                return level;
    }

};
```

The error:

> Now it don't show any errors, just don't get the sub-levels of the object.

I don't really get how it's all done by the tree, so I can't get why it isn't been readable.

Comment: Can you post the treemodel? I can post monday real tested code. Greetz chill

Comment: I have added the TreeModel!

Comment: @Sitansu and chillworld can't thank you guys enought ;) This was really givin' head aches here. Not only to me. Peace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this data in your zul:

```
 <treecell label="@load(each.numero)"/>
   <treecell label="@load(each.nome)"/>
```

Comment: Agree with sitansu. But see that your unidado class als have a getNome().

Comment: That didn't worked out.
@Sitansu I don't get the logic behind it. I have 4 columns, 2 of them will be for editing and deleting rows, and the 3th and 4th one will get the ID and the description of the Unidade class
How can I get exactly the properties of the class that I want, and put them in the rows that I want, removing the load ?

Comment: @chillworld I misspelled the propertie, it's Descricao actually, got that right already.
I do have an getDescricao and a getNumero on the class, and still it doesn't get it.
:(

Comment: @DaniloScanferla what is your fault when you removed the data?

Comment: @chillworld did youg guys actually told me to remove juist the .data from the label? Cuz yeah, that worked hahahaha
But now I have the itens renderized, but the tree don't show any sub-levels, just the 2 first items I added, I cannot open the itens I added.

Comment: As on the montarEstrutura() code, I have added 3 levels of treeItems, but the table just shows ub2 and ub3 on the treelist, and no sub-levers.

I'm really sorry if those questions are kinda newbies, but the structure of this component is complicated, and the zk don't seem to have enought documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Thats normal (cause you don't implemented the toString).

Now the problem is in your model(that was the test for).
First thing I would like to have changed is this :

```
public class UnidadeTreeModel extends AbstractTreeModel<Object> {
```

to

```
public class UnidadeTreeModel extends AbstractTreeModel<Unidade> {
```

This will helps you already with all the castings and get a nicer clean code.
Can you edit then the question with the new code of the model? That should help me with inspect the code faster.

Oke I did read your code a little intenser.
I have a problem with this :

```
public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
    String data = (String)child;
    int i = data.lastIndexOf('.');
    return Integer.parseInt(data.substring(i + 1));
}
```

What the ... are you doing there? String data will hold the adres (cause you don't have a toString)

Now try changing that to :

```
 public int getIndexOfChild(Unidade parent, Unidade child) {
    for (int i  = 0; i<parent.getUnidades().size();i++) {
        if (child.equals(parent.getUnidades().get(i))) { return i;}
    }
    return -1; //or throw exception what you want.
}
```

for the isLeaf (I don't know what about the 4th level but maybe you just can check with root?)

```
public boolean isLeaf(Unidade node) {
    return getRoot().equals(node);    
}
```

update latest question :

This I use to expand the tree after a button click :

```
private void doCollapseExpandAll(Component component, boolean aufklappen) {
    if (component instanceof Treeitem) {
        Treeitem treeitem = (Treeitem) component;
        treeitem.setOpen(aufklappen);
    }
    Collection<?> com = component.getChildren();
    if (com != null) {
        for (Iterator<?> iterator = com.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            doCollapseExpandAll((Component) iterator.next(), aufklappen);

        }
    }
}

public void fullyExpandTree(Component root){
    doCollapseExpandAll(root, true);
}
```

now you don't have to go all the way, just count to 4. I know you are smart enough to update that code ;).

Greetz chill.

Comment: No, now it gets the adress of the object instead of the name, and still doesn't get any children.

Comment: Ok, I edited the main code already.

I used to add the toString, and it really worked, but now it's not an option, as we don't want to update the Entity if we need to change the table, we want to just update the upper level of the code.

And now i'm gettin beaten up by that tree hahahaha like in harry potter

Comment: DUDE the isLeaf made the dif! Now I get the children !
Thanks a lot for that !

Only thing is the button that opens the node is on the 1st column, and I need it on the 3th one, can I make that happen ?

Comment: @Sitansu and Danilo please accept Sitansu's answer. He was correct for the original question, so he deserves the 15 points for that to. I'm already happy with the upvote ;).
Greetz chill.